# How to solve Access denied in gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

When I run : `git push`, there is exist error like this :

```
remote: Access denied
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/myname/mysystem.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Is there any people who can help me?

Comment: You don't have permission to push to that repository. `403` is the access forbidden error code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitLab remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied and fatal Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860772/gitlab-remote-http-basic-access-denied-and-fatal-authentication). This was first, but it seemingly solves the same problem

Comment: Add a new ssh public key to yourself via "Edit Profile Settings" under gitlab, if you are keeping different public-private pairs for each machine.  (also a note to self here)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add an SSH key to your GitLab and make sure git is using that key.

You can find this [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html) helpful.

Answer (score 21):

For Windows users, check this unbelievable easy solution, which works for me:

Go to Windows **Credential Manager** (press Windows Key and type 'credential') to edit the git entry under Windows Credentials. Replace old password with the new one.

Answer (score 14):

For Windows User

Go to Control Panel->Credential Manager->Windows Credentials select github or gitlab credentials and modify it. This is for windows10

[image]

Update your credentials again

and add access token here

https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens

Answer (score 6):

[What might help is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50597078/1587329)

> ```
> git config --system --unset credential.helper
> ```
>
> then enter new password for Git remote server.

Answer (score 5):

Basic Authentication / Access Denied issue fix:

1. Open Terminal from respect tool (Ex: Source Tree)
2. Execute this command -->
   git config --global credential.helper store
3. Execute this command -->
   git pull

   i) provide your user name
   2) provide your password

Answer (score 1):

check how to generate new password and try below

you can type in cmd

- git pull

Username for 'https://gitlab.XXX.xx': XXXX
Password for 'https://XXXX@gitlab.XXXX.xx': here u can enter new token
or
try this one also

1. Go to "control panel"
2. user accounts -manage credentials
3. windows credentials
4. git:https://username@gitlab.com
5. click on down
6. arrow Click remove. and add new token

Answer (score 0):

if you made your account by signing in with Github or Bitbucket, etc. add a password to your account so you can push, pull and clone with Gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

Very late here, but for posterity's sake:

If you do not have a gitlab password (initially signed up through github or something), then this will fail. You will just need to go to the page and create a password. At least that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today.
First was a blue screen of death in Windows 10 (I'm using git for windows connecting to a Azure DevOps repo), so after a restart, I was able to run `git status` and `git diff` both were fine, and then `git add .` that was also fine. When I got to `git push` I got an error unable to access.

I had cloned the repo and used the supplied git credentials initially and didn't have to enter any more credentials. So, I tried `git remote -v` and it listed the remote repo. After this I tried `git push` again, and It worked. An easy one to try before you go more difficult routes.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is getting this error also on non-Windows platforms with GitLab 13+. **There is another reason for this error apart from invalid credentials in your credential manager.**

I had a problem where my account was using LDAP for authentication but still had a password expiration date set. Because the server was configured to use LDAP authentication only, the password expiration was not visible in the web UI and became only an issue after [GitLab published a security fix with version 13.12.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/06/01/security-release-gitlab-13-12-2-released/#insufficient-expired-password-validation).

You can check and edit the `password_expires_at` attribute of a user account via the [GitLab Rails Console](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/troubleshooting/gitlab_rails_cheat_sheet.html#attributes). Setting it to `nil` solved the issue for me and got the LDAP authentication working again.