# Github beginner confusion

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to do a tutorial I found on Thinkster to build a Google+ clone using Angular and Django. I'm setting up the server from a GitHub repository but I'm doing it poorly somewhere.

In the README, I'm instructed to the following code:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:<your username>/thinkster-django-angular-boilerplate.git
```

throwing in my username (Andy Renz), I get this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I think there may be some issue because my username has a space in it so I don't think it copies to the right folder, it copies to this folder:

```
Cloning into 'Renz/thinkster-django-angular-boilerplate.git
```

which isn't correct but there also seems to be a permissions thing. Do you know what to do about the username issue or the permissions issue? Any help would be appreciated. I'd love to get started on this project.

Comment: Did you setup your github account for SSH access? If not, you have to do that first if you want to use SSH. See https://help.github.com/categories/ssh/ .

Comment: Maybe duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263662/how-to-solve-access-denied-in-gitlab/41264667#41264667 ?

Comment: 1st make sure you have cloned the original repository into your github account. 2nd, check your github username, I don't believe github allows usernames with spaces (and if it does, make a favour to yourself, and change it to don't have spaces)

Comment: You also have to make sure you fork the repository.  It isn't clear from your question if you've done this, but from some quick research it appears you have not.

Answer (score 2):

> throwing in my username (Andy Renz), I get this error:

For an ssh url, you always use the user '`git`'

GitHub will authenticate you from your public ssh key, that you must [add to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/).
Check the ssh setting is complete with `ssh -T github.com`

Regarding your username with space, try and [percent encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the space:

```
 Andy%20Renz
```

But GitHub probably transformed your username into a more sensible one.
For instance, I see https://github.com/andyrenzs, which means your username would then be `andyrenzs` (it might not be your account, but check your GitHub account url, to decude the username you should use).