# HTTP Basic: Access denied fatal: Authentication failed

Tags: git, gitlab

I use GitLab Community Edition 9.1.3 2e4e522 on Windows 10 Pro x64. With Git client.

Error

```
Cloning into 'project_name'...
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://my_user_name@example.com/my_user_name/project_name.git/'
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I got this issue in macOS High Sierra(10.13.5).How to fix it?

Comment: (I am not sure) On maCOS you open keychain, then remove credential https://support.apple.com/en-vn/guide/keychain-access/what-is-keychain-access-kyca1083/mac

Comment: I removed credential from keychain access.Still appear same error.

Comment: Answer is already given here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860772/gitlab-remote-http-basic-access-denied-and-fatal-authentication

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Open CMD (Run as administrator)
type command:

```
git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

then enter new password for Git remote server.

Comment: Removing or disabling the Git credential manager for Windows isn't really a solution to this problem. People have and use it because it's a necessary part of their workflow; perhaps because they use GitHub too. This repository needs to "just work" with it transparently.

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: doesn't work: gives 
error: could not lock config file /etc/gitconfig: Permission denied

Comment: It depends where you put your credentials. If the previous command does not work try also using global flag instead of system: `git config --global--unset credential.helper`

Comment: run command as administrator, nothing happens. (windows7, gitlab)

Comment: perfect solution, this usually happens when your git password has changed and your system's git credential helper is looking to authenticate using the older token. Do this to unset your credentials and re run your git command. It should ask for an authentication after that you're good  to go.

Comment: error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi You have to run cmd as administrator. Try rerunning the command after that.

Comment: There are other ways to change the password: [macos - How do I update the password for Git? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195304/how-do-i-update-the-password-for-git)

Answer (score 28):

Im my case i was using Git Credential Manager for Windows (it was installed by default, I didn't install it manually)

Credentials Manager had saved my old password but i changed it lately.

If you are in the same conditions, to solve this problem:
Go to Control Panel -> Credentials Manager and delete git account.
After that it will ask you again for the credentials.

Comment: My gitlab account is connected with Github. And I'm facing this issue

Comment: I'm using GitHub password for that. And This is my first commit to the branch.

Comment: @KlevisGjN I'm facing this issue in Window 10 Pro

Answer (score 14):

For my case, I initially tried with

> git config --system --unset credential.helper

But I was getting error

> error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig: Permission denied

Then tried with

> git config --global --unset credential.helper

No error, but still got access denied error while git pulling.

Then went to Control Panel -> Credentials Manager > Windows Credential and deleted git account.

After that when I tried git pull again, it asked for the credentials and a new git account added in Credentails manager.

Comment: Control Panel -> Credentials Manager > Windows Credential and Edit Worked for me for 2 options under gitlab accounts.

Answer (score 8):

i coped with same error and my suggestion are:

1. Start with try build another user in git lab
2. Recheck username & password (although it sounds obvious)
3. Validate the windows credential (start -> "cred")
4. Copy & paste same URL like you get from git lab, the struct should be:

> http://{srvName}/{userInGitLab}/{Repository.git}
> no '/' at the end

5. Recheck the authorization in GitLab
6. Give an attention to case sensitive

Hope one of the above will solve it.

Comment: That's work! I have the wrong password typo at the first time, just change it in the windows credential. there is no way to re-input from git-tortoise.

Answer (score 6):

If username and password is prompted. Just add Gitlab username and password for clone.

For pop up dialog asking credential, follow the steps below.

> 1. Go to "control panel"
> 2. user accounts
> 3. manage credentials
> 4. windows credentials
> 5. git:https://username@gitlab.com
> 6. click on down arrow
> 7. Click remove.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

This can happen also because of a change in the password and since Git Credential Manager caches it, so if that's the case 
1. Open Credential Manager in Windows 
2. Search for your GIT credential and reset it to the new password.

Answer (score 4):

Go to your Credential manager => git credentials 
Check your git credentials and check your password.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

1. Generate an access token with never expire date, and select all the options available.
2. Remove the existing SSH keys.
3. Clone the repo with the https instead of ssh.
4. Use the username but use the generated access token instead of password.

[image]

alternatively you can set remote to http by using this command in the existing repo, and use this command git remote set-url origin [https://gitlab.com/[username]/[repo-name].git](https://gitlab.com/%5Busername%5D/%5Brepo-name%5D.git)

Answer (score 4):

in ubuntu 20.04 ,

vscode terminal was unable to pull/push
returned this error

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for
```

Simply opened regular terminal in the folder location
git pull/push
worked properly

Comment: It's a workaround, not a solution. But works!

Comment: it works for me, thanks

Answer (score 3):

## Before digging into the solution lets first see why this happens.

Before any transaction with git that your machine does git checks for your authentication which can be done using

1. An SSH key token present in your machine and shared with git-repo(most preferred)
   **OR**
2. Using your username/password (mostly used)

### Why did this happen

In simple words, this happened because the credentials stored in your machine are not authentic i.e.there are chances that your password stored in the machine has changed from whats there in git therefore

### Solution

Head towards, control panel and search for **Credential Manager** look for your use git url and change the creds.

There you go this works with mostly every that windows keep track off

Answer (score 1):

A simple git fetch/pull command will throw a authentication failed message. But do the same git fetch/pull command second time, and it should prompt a window asking for credential(username/password). Enter your Id and new password and it should save and move on.

Answer (score 1):

I use VS Code on my mac OS and GitLab for my project. I tried so many ways but it worked simply for me by resetting the remote origin of your project repository with the below command:

```
cd <local-project-repo-on-machine>
git remote set-url <remote-name> <remote-url>

for ex: git remote set-url origin https://<project-repository>.git
```

Hope it helps someone.

[macos](/questions/tagged/macos)[git](/questions/tagged/git)[gitlab](/questions/tagged/gitlab)[authentication](/questions/tagged/authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the entry(possibly the password field that may have changed) for git: inside Generic Credentials section of Windows Credentials which can be accessed from Control Panel. Please note this is for Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with:

1. Deleting the github credential from the windows credentials,
2. Adding a new credential like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59818208/11865149) (the password is the PAT)

Answer (score 0):

```
stderr: remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied fatal: Authentication failed for
```

I found out that I got this error because I entered the wrong password in the credential on Jenkins. When I made sure I typed the correct password, my problem was solved. git fetch etc. via server. You can run a command and make sure that the username and password are correct.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting the error:

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied fatal: Authentication failed for xxxxx
```

Make sure your gitlab user name DOES NOT contain a dash.

For example, I had:  `CI-test@mydomain.com` which returned the error above.

I changed it to:  `CItest@mydomain.com`, and it did not return the error.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after my access token expired.

1. Follow Gitlab's [instructions](https://kp2.in.htwg-konstanz.de/git/help/api/README.md#personal-access-tokens) to generate a PAT. **Copy and
   paste the token.**
2. Go to Credential Manager (you can find this in Control Panel > User Accounts)
3. Edit the password for git:https://gitlab.com replacing it with the PAT you generated.

Answer (score -1):

The updating of the password in the windows credential manager was not the solution for me.

I had to set a different remote url, by:

`git remote set-url origin https://gitlab....git`

The url in this case was the one that could be found in Gitlab under Clone -> Clone with HTTPS. It was not the one in the command line instructions.

Answer (score -2):

- Try if it works on the Git Bash
- Have you added a ssh key to your account? If yes remove it and try
  again. If not add one and try the ssh url.
- You don't necessarily need Tortoise Git but it may also work around
  your problem
- Try to re-install Git without the Git Credential Manager for Windows

When you've fixed the push problem you will also be able to clone it when it is private or internal.