# How to reset git authentication?

Tags: git, gitlab

I typed wrong ID (my mistake) and I think my computer's IP is permanently banned. I'd like to un-ban my IP so that I can git clone to my desired git repository. But when I tried to git clone my git repository, it says
`remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied`
`fatal: Authentication failed for "~~my repository"`

How can I access my git repository again? Or how can I reset my banned state? I think typing a wrong ID only once and be permanently banned is somewhat harsh.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove credentials from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)

Comment: Answer is already given on : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860772/gitlab-remote-http-basic-access-denied-and-fatal-authentication/51042334#51042334

Answer (score 95, accepted):

It seems that your credential manager stored wrong authentication and reuses it. Reset it.

```
git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

More information:

[Remove credentials from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)

[GitLab remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied and fatal Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860772/gitlab-remote-http-basic-access-denied-and-fatal-authentication)

Comment: If on windows you get a permission denied message just run your cmd as administrator

Comment: good, solved the problem like a charm (on a fresh new install)

Comment: As much as it might “work” it does not seem to be sane, and it probably won't work the second time around. Because that config is setting where to store the credentials, not storing the credenaials. So by this command you switch to different location for storing credentials, which has the effect of not having them, but a) it's less secure and b) next time you won't have any third place to switch to.

Comment: Note that this deletes all credentials and completely disables the helper.

Answer (score 6):

I think this article may serve you better: [Github OpenSSH asking for password for an https link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git#:%7E:text=You%20could%20also%20disable%20use,%2D%2Dsystem%20%2D%2Dunset%20credential.)

To unset the `git config --system --unset credential.helper` command, you can do type `git config --system credential.helper` store (maybe also with `--global` and `--local` flag)

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 10,

Open `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager` path via file explorer or search `"Credentials Manager"` keyword from windows  bottom search field. Then click the `"Windows Credentials"` section.

Select your git server and than click the edit button as shown the picture. Lastly, update your credentials. Save it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

@ikh's answer works, but I had to set it to it's original value afterwards:

```
$ git config --system credential.helper
manager-core
$ git config --system --unset credential.helper
 ... log in again and be prompted for credentials ...
$ git config --system credential.helper manager-core
```

It's still quite a hack.

Answer (score 0):

If the cached credential app is storing wrong data you need to remove cached/stored credentials from there. To see how to remove from **wincred** see [Remove credentials from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)

---

**Resetting credential app**

The auth can be broken at different levels.

```
#list all 
git config --list --show-origin --show-scope |grep credential.helper
#reset
git config --system --unset credential.helper
git config --global --unset credential.helper
git config --local --unset credential.helper
```

In my case was at global (user)

```
global  file:d:/home/raiser/.gitconfig  credential.helperselector.selected=wincred
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete only one token, use `git credential-store erase`.

For example, to delete the currently used GitHub token, use:

```bash
echo -e "protocol=https\nhost=github.com" | git credential-store erase
```