# GitLab: Remote access denied fatal - authentication failed

Tags: git, gitlab

yesterday i was coding, when i do the commit into a repo, i cannot do it because, gitlab send me two messages.

this message appears at the moment i was trying to commit

1. On branch master
   Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

after when i insert "git pull"

2. remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
   fatal: Authentication failed for (link of the repository)

"git push"

remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for

help me please!

Comment: you don't have permissions, check in the repository or update ssh keys if applies

Answer (score 8):

I think it's too late, But if some windows user is having the issue. Here is the working solution.
I have updated my credentials on gitlab. Git bash stores credentials in the Windows Vault using Generic Credentials in the `'Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager'`. After updating my password to match the current value I was able to 'git push'.

Answer (score 2):

now is 2021 year, the most possible reason is:

Gitlab not allow password access, but recommend use: `access token`.

- how to use Gitlab access token?

  - Core Logic:

    - **create token**: in gitlab `Profile`->`Settings`->`Access Tokens`->input name, select all, `create personal access token`
    - **use access token instead of git password**: when git push, (in popup window) need input `access token` (into password field), **NOT** use `git password`
  - Detailed steps: please refer [JavAlex's answer in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51133684/1616263) (I have updated my answer into it)

Answer (score 0):

First generate pair of ssh-key on your local git bash

Open Git bash Terminal and type this

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "youremailaddress"
```

Then press enter and enter

then do `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

and copy the contents of the id_rsa.pub file to your clipboard and go to your gitlab profile `settings >> ssh key` and paste this key and done

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is getting this error also on non-Windows platforms with GitLab 13+. There is another reason apart from invalid credentials.

I had a problem where my account was using LDAP for authentication but still had a password expiration date set. Because the server was configured to use LDAP authentication only, the password expiration was not visible in the web UI and became only an issue after [GitLab published a security fix with version 13.12.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/06/01/security-release-gitlab-13-12-2-released/#insufficient-expired-password-validation).

You can check and edit the `password_expires_at` attribute of a user account via the [GitLab Rails Console](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/troubleshooting/gitlab_rails_cheat_sheet.html#attributes). Setting it to `nil` solved the issue and got the LDAP authentication working again.