# Unable to clone repository from Gitlab: Permission denied, please try again

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys, git-clone

I'm trying to clone an empty repository from my Gitlab account. I simply use the address shown on my Gitlab repository page under `SSH`:

```
git@gitlab.xxx.com:USERNAME/project-name.git
```

[image]

Then simply try this in an empty folder, but it keeps telling me permission denided, asking for retry:

```
git clone git@gitlab.xxx.com:USERNAME/project-name.git
Cloning into 'project-name'...
git@gitlab.xxx.com's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
git@gitlab.xxx.com's password:
```

and when I choose the `https` address for clone, this is the message:

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for ....
```

I am able to login to `Gitlab` homepage with that password, so I don't know what is really wrong.

What is wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: You are missing a SSH key here

Comment: ummm, what is the solution?!

Comment: `git clone http://gitlab.xxx.com/project-name.git` will ask for user and password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub Error Message - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+ssh+authentication

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitLab remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied and fatal Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860772/gitlab-remote-http-basic-access-denied-and-fatal-authentication)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I'm in Windows, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092795/9338572) was the life saver:

It happen every time I'm forced to change the Windows password and none of above answers helped to me.

Try below solution which works for me:

Go to **Windows Credential Manager** (press `Windows Key` and type `credential`) to edit the git entry under `Windows Credentials`. Replace old password with the new one.

Answer (score 3):

ssh authentication on Gitlab requires a ssh key. You need to generate one, depending on your host, windows, linux or other. Then you need to add the key to your account.

You can find all the required information here: https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README.md

If you want to use your http login you should switch to http authentication. At the left of the repository address there's a menu, you can choose ssh or http. Use the latter

Comment: Still not working: `remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for ....`

Comment: @TinaJ maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860772/gitlab-remote-http-basic-access-denied-and-fatal-authentication) helps?

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked for me was to use:

```
$ git clone ssh://git@192.168.200.100:2022/USERNAME/project-name.git
```

I'll break this down as there are a three parts here:

1. It was **critical** to specify "ssh://" and change ":USERNAME" to "/USERNAME".
2. *I do not have a hostname configured* for this machine, so I used the IP Address.
3. *I'm running GitLab in a docker container and port 22 is forwarded* via port 2022.

In summary, GitLab suggests this format:

```
git@192.168.200.100:USERNAME/project-name.git
```

which results in:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

regardless of whether the correct password is entered or a password is even set.  Instead, the following format works:

```
ssh://git@192.168.200.100/USERNAME/project-name.git
```

GLHF!