# remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied

Tags: git, gitlab

Hi I'm facing access denied problem, I have updated SSL key, haven't changed password. I have this issue for all git remote operations for all the projects.
can some one please assist.

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git clone https://git.platform.manulife.io/conversational-channels/vivr-jacada-ui.git
08:49:35.481599 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin
08:49:35.483582 git.c:440               trace: built-in: git clone https://git.platform.manulife.io/conversational-channels/vivr-jacada-ui.git
Cloning into 'vivr-jacada-ui'...
08:49:35.530206 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git remote-https origin https://git.platform.manulife.io/conversational-channels/vivr-jacada-ui.git
08:49:35.575342 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
08:49:35.581789 git.c:703               trace: exec: git-remote-https origin https://git.platform.manulife.io/conversational-channels/vivr-jacada-ui.git
08:49:35.581789 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin https://git.platform.manulife.io/conversational-channels/vivr-jacada-ui.git
08:49:35.625438 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
08:49:35.751423 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: 'git credential-manager get'
08:49:35.852606 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
08:49:35.855582 git.c:703               trace: exec: git-credential-manager get
08:49:35.855582 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git-credential-manager get
08:49:36.388781 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: 'git credential-manager erase'
08:49:36.482029 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
08:49:36.485005 git.c:703               trace: exec: git-credential-manager erase
08:49:36.485005 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git-credential-manager erase
08:49:36.797981 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: 'git credential-manager erase'
08:49:36.893709 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
08:49:36.896686 git.c:703               trace: exec: git-credential-manager erase
08:49:36.896686 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git-credential-manager erase
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
```

Comment: Do you have the access permission?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitLab remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied and fatal Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860772/gitlab-remote-http-basic-access-denied-and-fatal-authentication)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remote%3A+HTTP+Basic%3A+Access+denied

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem when I was entering my username and password and made a typo. After that I kept getting "Access Denied".

FIX:
Open Windows crontrol panel, Search for passwords from the top right, Click on "Windows Credentials". In the list you should see something like git:https://gitlab.your.domain.com. Remove it.

Run your git-clone command again and a pop up window should allow you to enter your credentials again.

If you still get the same error. Check that your Windows account is not locked out by all of the failed attempts.

Comment: Search `Credential Manager` in the search window and edit your credentials for the associated cite.