# Push to Gitlab with access token using Github Actions

Tags: git, gitlab, github-actions

First of all, I am quite new to Github Actions.

And I was trying to use Github Actions to automatically push my repo to Gitlab with access token. However, I was always getting error `remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/chuang_/jskara-web.git/'`

I tried the solution in [GitLab remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied and fatal Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860772/gitlab-remote-http-basic-access-denied-and-fatal-authentication), `git config --system --unset credential.helper`, but if I put that line in the .yml, it will break and return error code 5. If I don't put that line, I will get the error described above.

My .yml file with tried history: https://github.com/ChuangSheep/javascript-kara-web/blob/master/.github/workflows/pushToGitlab.yml

And here my latest attempt

```
name: PushGitlab

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with: 
        fetch-depth: 0
      env: 
        token: ${{ secrets.GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN }}

    - name: Push To Gitlab
      run: |
        echo Starting to push repo to gitlab
        git config user.name "ChuangSheep"
        git config user.email "44814054+ChuangSheep@users.noreply.github.com"
        git remote set-url origin "https://oauth2:${token}@gitlab.com/chuang_/jskara-web.git"
        git push origin master
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving `env` block with token to "Push to Gitlab" step. Currently you set remote url to `https://oauth2:@gitlab.com/chuang_/jskara-web.git` as `token` variable is never set.

Comment: Thank you and it worked. I have misnderstood the meaning of a `environmental variable`.