# fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': No such device or address on gitlab

Tags: linux, git, continuous-integration, gitlab, devops

I am Try to push code with automate deploy and pull process to the production server, but I got an error in the pipeline build process like this

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.com': No such device or address
```

here is a `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
script:
- mkdir -p ~/.ssh
- chmod 700 ~/.ssh
- echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
- echo "$PRIVATE_KEY_STAGING" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
- chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
- ssh -p22 ec2-user@$SERVER_STAGING "uname -a"
```

How to Login to My Server and pull my updated code using Gitlab CI/CD?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is probably a Docker issue. It's definitely not a Git thing.

Comment: this is authentication for private repo, how to bypass it? torek

Comment: You don't *bypass* it so much as figure out what "device or address" the program needs (/dev/random? /dev/tty? I don't know, the complaint is weird here) and make sure that the right mount points are instantiated in your Docker setup.

Comment: I have checked my docker configuration and all passed, but if I pull git repo in the server, this require username and password

Comment: There is no `git pull` command in your script, so what's running `git pull`? Why is it not using ssh authentication or a PAT?

Comment: solved, I use personal Access Token to pull my private repo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitLab remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied and fatal Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860772/gitlab-remote-http-basic-access-denied-and-fatal-authentication)

Answer (score 2):

Since you got it resolved, how about to describe better here what have you done?

It may be more usefull to the community rather then a simple

> "solved, I use personal Access Token to pull my private repo"