# How to pass Gitlab Credentials in Custom Runner

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration, cicd

I have created a custom Gitlab CI/CD runner. I used project based token.

```
New-Item -Path 'C:\GitLab-Runner' -ItemType Directory

cd 'C:\GitLab-Runner'

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/binaries/gitlab-runner-windows-amd64.exe" -OutFile "gitlab-runner.exe"

.\gitlab-runner.exe install
.\gitlab-runner.exe start

./gitlab-runner.exe register --url http://gitlab.my-company.net/ --registration-token $REGISTRATION_TOKEN
```

The token I get from the UI,

[image]

But I am getting this error,

> remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password.

Comment: Where, exactly are you seeing that error? When registering the runner or trying to run a job on that runner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to check the version of GitLab used.

As noted in "[Registering runners (deprecated)](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/)"

> The ability to pass a runner registration token was [deprecated](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/380872) in GitLab 15.6 and is planned for removal in 17.0, along with support for certain configuration arguments
>
> GitLab plans to introduce a new [GitLab Runner token architecture](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/architecture/blueprints/runner_tokens/), which introduces a new method for registering runners and eliminates the legacy [runner registration token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/token_overview.html#runner-registration-tokens).

[Thread 82118](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-runner-no-access-to-private-repository-http-basic-access-denied/82118) also follows that issue:

> Did you perhaps have some form of LDAP or SSO authentication in place on Gitlab?
> I ran into an issue where our runner was trying to authenticate with LDAP/Kerberos under the hood, which was failing.
> We thought it was an issue with the `CI_JOB_TOKEN`, but that was not the issue.

The [OP Imran Qadir Baksh - Baloch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960567/imran-qadir-baksh-baloch) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75948803/how-to-pass-gitlab-credentials-in-custom-runner/75948903#comment133968408_75948903):

> As shown in "[Gitlab Pipeline failing "remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72381700/6309)", adding `clone_url` fixed it.
>
> Now, I am getting
>
> ```
> Exception calling "WriteAllText" with "2" argument(s): 
> "Access to the path 'c:\builds\xxx\xxx.tmp\CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE' is denied."
> ```
>
> And that is fixed by using `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.202-windowsservercore-ltsc2019`, as mentioned in [`gitlab-org/gitlab-runner` issue 27891](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/27891).

Comment: My Gitlab version is 15.2.5-ee

Comment: Although gitlab has "deprecated" registration, they have not yet introduced its replacement. Clarified in [this thread](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/380872#note_1199851762) it is not yet actually deprecated, but rather _will be_ deprecated.

Comment: @sytech Good point. Let's wait for the OP's feedback.

Comment: Adding  clone_url fixed it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72381700/gitlab-pipeline-failing-remote-http-basic-access-denied. Now, I am getting Exception calling "WriteAllText" with "2" argument(s): "Access to the path 'c:\builds\xxx\xxx.tmp\CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE' is denied."

Comment: Second issue is also fixed by using `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.202-windowsservercore-ltsc2019` https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/27891

Comment: @ImranQadirBaksh-Baloch Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comments in the answer for more visibility.