# HTTP Basic: Access denied. for only one project

Tags: git, gitlab, git-push

when ever I try to push from device to GitLab server I keep getting error

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See https://gitlab.com/help/topics/git/troubleshooting_gi
t#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied
```

Now hear me out completely before reacting, I do know there are many questions similar to this , like

[GitLab remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied and fatal Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860772/gitlab-remote-http-basic-access-denied-and-fatal-authentication)

but here is where my problem lies, This issue only occurs for one project , for other projects in the same device and same location *(I mean same SSD)* to same Gitlab account there is no issue I'm, able to push and pull without any problem.

I could use the access token to resolve this issue, but why is it require only for one project and not for the others?

PS: I'm facing this issue both in my editor and terminal

---

Linking this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/how-do-i-change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository)

Comment: you've cloned the project from http url? or ssh url?

Comment: The link you cited (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092795/421195) is a good one.  Q: What OS is your Git client running on?  Windows?  If so, have you checked Windows Credential Mgr?  Q: Have you compared project settings between your "one" and "the others" (e.g. `git config --list`)?  Q: Have you compared GitLab rep settings?

Comment: @paulsm4 yes, i have checked their settings both in my device and gitLab they are same, it's running in Windows but if the credential Manger was an issue it should effect all my projects and not just one.

Comment: @MonishKhatri i have initialized both the projects from my device using `git init`  they were not created in git  and then cloned.

Comment: Have you tried to use SSH instead of HTTPS? That should overcome the 2FA hurdle the error is prompting.

Comment: @AkashJain , Yes you haved init in local but from which url you've cloned the projects.

Comment: @MonishKhatri do you mean `origin add` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first the exact URL used for pushing:

```bash
cd C:\path\to\repository
git remote -v
```

Since you have created them locally, that means you must have set the remote "origin" at some point. (`git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/you/YourRemoteRepo`)

Check also the cached credentials.

In a CMD, make sure:

- the `<path/to/Git>/mingw64/bin` is in your `%PATH%`/`$PATH`: that is where `git-credential-manager-core` will reside (for recent Git versions anyway 2.35+).
- the `<path/to/Git>/usr/bin` is in your `%PATH%`/`$PATH`: that is where `printf` will reside (needed for Windows OS which does not have a built-in shell `printf` command in its shell).

From there:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https" | git credential-manager-core get
```

Comment: I'm not able to find `<path/to/Git>/bin/bin` there is only `<path/to/Git>/bin` which does not contain the `printf` command

Comment: @AkashJain On Windows, it is `C:\Program Files\Git`. What version of Git are you using?

Comment: No it's in another Drive, git verson `2.37`

Comment: @AkashJain OK, then replace C:\ by your other drive.

Comment: Hi @VonC it's not present in the  path, i could find the `git-credential-manager-core` and `my_path/bin`  but not the `printf` or `my_path/bin/bin`

Comment: @AkashJain You did replace `my_path` with your Git installation path, right?

Comment: yes,  `my_path` is not actually a valid path

Comment: @AkashJain I do have a printf.exe in `c:\Path\to\Git\usr\bin\printf.exe`

Comment: i see the path you have mentioned in the answer is incorrect then, cause it's `my_path/bin/bin` let me find in `my_path/usr/bin`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247789/discussion-between-vonc-and-akash-jain).