# GitLab remote: Access denied with GitLab via GitHub authorization

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Unlike [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860772/gitlab-remote-http-basic-access-denied-and-fatal-authentication) im authorized in gitLab via GitHub

I am authorized in gitLab via gitHub and I trying to clone project with URL.

So when I trying to do steps below for a new project I am prompted to enter my gitlab account login and password

```
git init
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/Egas88/web_lab_2.git
git fetch
```

after data is entered for both gitLab and GitHub I get the following error

> Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token
> instead of a password. See https://gitlab.com/help/topics/git/troubleshooting_git#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied
> fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/Egas88/web_lab_2.git/'

I tried to change rights from developer to maintainer and I still get this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that you clarified if you have a 2FA enabled or not... But I'll assume that you do for this answer.

Try using your Personal Access Token instead of your password.
You can find instructions [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#create-a-personal-access-token) on how to create a Personal Access Token.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should change your password for GitLab in Windows  credential manager

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

All the scenarios and needed actions for this error are explained under the GitLab link that you get with the error.