# Git after access denied

Tags: git

The password of a repo got updated so I had [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860772/gitlab-remote-http-basic-access-denied-and-fatal-authentication) (Access denied)

so I did

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

and now I can fetch .

Problem is now it asks for the user and password every time. How can I fix it so that it does not ask it anymore (as it was before)

Comment: From the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51036707/112968

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitLab remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied and fatal Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860772/gitlab-remote-http-basic-access-denied-and-fatal-authentication)

Comment: @Valeriia I mentioned that question in my own question. Which part would be the answer?

Comment: @KansaiRobot did you click my link? It links directly to an answer to that question (which should provide a solution – if it doesn't, please clarify)